# Django advanced query with "or"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Here are my models (very complex, I use letter to simplify):

```
class W(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    is_important = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)

class Se(models.Model):
    ws = models.ManyToManyField(W)

class Ra(models.Model):
    ses = models.ManyToManyField(Se)

class Pq(models.Model):
    ras = models.ForeignKey(Ra)

class PqSe(models.Model):
    pq = models.ForeignKey(Pq)
    se = models.ForeignKey(Phrase)

class PqSeW(models.Model):
    pq_se = models.ForeignKey(PqSe)
    w = models.ForeignKey(W)
    idx = models.IntegerField(blank=False)

class Person(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

class PersonPqSeW(models.Model):
    pq_se_w = models.ForeignKey('PqSeW')
    is_valid = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False)
```

What I need is, *for a given `Pq`*, to have all the `Se`'s that contain:

- either `W`'s that are important (`is_important=True`) and not in `PersonPqSeW`
- **or** `W`'s that are important (`is_important=True`) and in `PersonPqSeW`, but are not valid (`is_valid=False`).

Comment: When you say a set A of `W`'s that are not in `PersonPqSeW` do you mean `PersonPqSeW`'s that have `PqSeW` whose 'W' field is not in set A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

se_qs = Se.objects\
    .filter(pqse__pq=pq, ws__is_important=True)\
    .exclude(Q(pqse__pqsew__personpqsew__is_valid=False) | 
             Q(pqse__pqsew__personpqsew__isnull=False))
```

Basically, they idea is to exclude the irrelevant records. 
The complexity is in querying the nested relationships. More on this can be read in [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#spanning-multi-valued-relationships)

Also, if you want to make it more readable, I would encourage you to look into using [`related_name` for Foreign Keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)

Also, relevant documentation on [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's perfect.